# Expected value exists because it has an integrable lower bound?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

I'm trying to understand an argument my prof made:

> Given $h:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ convex, we look at $E[h(X)]$. The expected value exists because $h(X)$ is lower-bounded by [some] $l(X)$ that is integrable.

I'm not certain why this lower bound implies that the expected value exists. I know, of course, Lebesgue's theorem about dominated convergence but that refers to an upper bound.

So I tried to search for a different reason behind it and I came up with this:
We have $E(h(X)^-) \leq E(l(X)^-) < \infty$ since $l(X) \leq h(X)$. Our lecture then implies that $E(h(X))$ exists already.

But couldn't we just use that argument in generalization and we get that whenever an $X$ is lower bounded by some integrable $Y$ random variable, then $E(X)$ exists.

Is that correct?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "exists": Is it allowed to be infinity? For example take any random variable $X$ with infinite second moment, then $0\leq X^2$ and $E[0]\leq E[X^2]=\infty$.  [This example has $l(X)=0$ and $h(X)=X^2$]

Comment: Note that if $W\leq Z$ surely then $Z-W\geq 0$ surely and so $E[Z-W]\geq 0$ (the value of $E[Z-W]$ possibly being $\infty$).

Comment: Is it the case that $X$ is integrable?

Comment: @JohnDawkins yes it is. But why do we need that? The argument holds true, doesn't it? And yes, it is allowed to be infinity

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $X$ to be integrable:  By convexity, $h$ is bounded below by affine $l$; and $l(X)$ is integrable because $X$ is so. In particular, $E[l(X)^-]<\infty$. (Where $b^-:=\max(-b,0)$.) Therefore, because $h(x)^-\le l(x)^-$ for all $x$, $E[h(X)^-]\le E[l(X)^-]<\infty$. Consequently, $E[h(X)]$ is well defined as $E[h(X)^+]-E[h(X)^-]$, although $E[h(X)]$  might take the value $+\infty$.